# How can i get website text wothout using web browser?

Tags: c#

I tryed to do a webbrowser that fro, him i get the text.
But insted of getting the text is downloading to my computer the file.
How can i get this text without using it?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to understand. Would you mind re-phrasing and providing some more detail?

Comment: Please revise your question, can't even understand what it is you're are attempting to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
string output = string.Empty;
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    output = wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```